# MonoDroid - Target Device does not display in IDE

Tags: android, android-emulator, monodevelop, xamarin.android, adb

I'm trying to run the very simplest app on MonoDroid though the MonoDevelop IDE - i.e. the one that is created as part of the new project (the one that increments the lable on button clicks - i won't post code as I don't think it is relevant unless someone really wants it).

When I press the run menu item then run (or debug) i get the emulator selection

[image]

I dutifully start the emulator - (I've tried API_7, API_10, API_12) and that works OK. But the IDE above never refreshes to show the currently running emulator so I can't launch the application. I have manually refreshed but the same list comes up. What I am expecting is the new emulator to appear in the list and the OK button becoming active.

I have tried running `adb device`s in the command line and I can see that the debug bridge has picked up the device i.e. it says `emulator-5554` which matches the TCP/IP port that the emulator is running on.

I've also tried restarting the debug server i.e.

```
adb kill-server
adb restart-server
```

But I can't see the emulator appear on the above dialog. The debug server is running on port 5037. Could the IDE be listening to a different port?

Fundamentally I'm trying to get the simplest app running through MonoDevelop. And I'm failing. Please help good people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem initially when I tried running the emulators. My recommendations from my own experience would be to:

1. Run the Android SDK manager and retrieve all the latest SDK packages.
2. Create your own Android Virtual Device via the AVD Manager rather than running those that are listed when the IDE is intially run. You should then start the AVD manually via the AVD manager and ensure it is fully loaded before starting the de-bug.

Comment: I was behind a proxy - so I needed to put the proxy in the AVD manager to get this working. But this is correct - for some reason the SDKs out of the box weren't registering. An update and a new SDK then this works. Also the emulated device needs to be unlocked to register